# Laurent series of $e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$ for $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}$ in a Laurent series for $|z|>1$
We have :$$e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=e^{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}}$$

So $$e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}= 1 +(1+z+z^2+...)+\frac{1}{2}(1+z+z^2+...)^2 +...$$

The result is $$e^{\frac{1}{z-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{z^n}$$ 
Where $$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{1}{k!}$$

Edit :
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1} \frac{1}{k!}$$
Is there a trick to find the result without a lot of calculation ?

Thank you ...

Comment: I don't think the $a_n$ you found is correct, but either way, why do you not simply do $$e^{\frac1{z-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!(z-1)^k}\ \ \text{ ?}$$

Comment: Do you need to find the Laurent series at $z=0$ or$z=1$?

Comment: This is the answer in the book

Comment: Laurent series for $|z|>1$

Comment: Yes you're right thank you .

Comment: Given the form of your third line, I think you're looking for a Laurent series about $z = \infty$, in which case you'll want to expand $1/(z-1)$ about $\infty$ as well rather than about 0.  You have such an expansion in your first line, but not your second line.